# Styling UIButtons - subclass?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I have four buttons that are going to be styled in the same way on the same scene (using Storyboard).  This is simple styling that will require overriding a few of the property defaults, but seems needlessly repetitive to set this for each individual button. I was thinking I’d create a subclass, but a lot of the posts I’ve read (particularly on stackoverflow) warn against doing this for UIButton (and the attempts I’ve made haven’t been successful).

Just hoping to get a general pointer on what’s considered the best approach for this.  Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are targeting only iOS 5, I strongly recommend watching **[Session 114 - Customizing the Appearance of UIKit Controls](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/?id=114)**<sub>developer login required</sub> of the *WWDC 2011 Session Videos*.

It explains in detail App-wide styling.

---

I want to modify yujis idea: Use a [category](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Category.html) on UIButton to setup the button

*.h.*

```
@interface UIButton (MyStyling)
-(void)configureMyButtonStyle;
//other methods for more fine-grained control
@end
```

*.m*

```
@implementation UIButton (MyStyling)
-(void)configureMyButtonStyle
{
    [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:…]];
    [self setTitleColor: [UIColor colorWithRed:…] forState: UIControlStateNormal];
    //…

}
@end
```

Now you can call `[aButton configureMyButtonStyle]`

Of course you can also parse in some parameters, to distinguish several style.

```
-(void)configureMyButtonForStyle:(NSInteger)style
{
    if(style == 1){
        //…
    } else if(style == 2) {
       //..
    } else {
       //fallback style 
    }
}
```

use:

```
[aButton configureMyButtonForStyle:1];
```

Comment: Thanks for that - setting up a category makes sense - especially since I'll use the same button styling on a few different views. And that appearance proxy I just learned about courtesy of your link may provide another option too.

Answer (score 4):

Subclassing seems like overkill here. You could just write a method that sets the properties the way you want in one of your controllers, and call that on each `UIButton`.

Or you could always just customize one button the way you want in IB, then copy-and-paste three times.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - method it is.